# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate object throwing Exception

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to query a sql in my springs application. Now if my code includes something like-

```
String sql="select abc,def from alphabets where character=:charValue";
SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource("charValue","ac");
List li = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, paramMap);
```

Now when I am running my application this code is throwing :

> org.springframework.dao.PermissionDeniedDataAccessException

I have tried everything and I feel that I am facing the issue when I am querying for the list using namedParameterJdbcTemplate.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you do not have permission to access database/database table, check http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/dao/PermissionDeniedDataAccessException.html

Comment: You can rule out if the `namedParameter` is causing your problems by simply trying to do the query without it. Nevertheless, adding a parameter to a query won't lead to a `PermissionDeniedDataAccessException`

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PermissionDeniedDataAccessException
extends DataAccessException

Exception thrown when the underlying resource denied a permission to access a specific element, such as a specific database table.
```

Do you have permission to access `alphabets` table ?